# load js file in requirejs-config.js in magento2

Tags: javascript, php, requirejs, magento2, model-viewer

how to load this js file in requirejs?

```
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
```

my requirejs-config.js file=?

```
var config = {
  paths: {
    modelviewer: "Ajith_CustomModule/js/modelviewer.min",
       .....
       .....
       .....
```

and load this file in my phtml file

```
<script type="module">


require(['jquery'.......,'modelviewer'],function($,..,model){
});

</script>
    .....
    ..... 
   .....
```

shows this error =>
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

anybody please help me to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: RequireJS is not compatible with module type of scripts

Comment: then how can I load this js file ?

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS does not support native JS modules. You have to load it as regular JS module, working example:

```html
<script type="module">
  import { ModelViewerElement } from 'https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js';
  
  console.log(ModelViewerElement);
</script>
```

(tested on Chrome 96)